# Disable Sonar duplications on Entity, DTO packages

Tags: java, static-analysis, sonarqube

Is there any way to disable certain metrics from selected packages in Sonar? I use Sonar to analyze my project and in Entity and DTO packages I have some code that is equal - the same field ID with annotations, etc is being reported as a duplication by Sonar. It has absolutely no sense to me so I'd like to disable it. How can I achieve this? Using the global exclusions option disables all metrics on selected package but how to do it just for code duplications?

Comment: I was also facing 'duplication' issue from sonar, the details helped to identify the issue easily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exclude resources using the standard ["sonar.exclusions"](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus) parameter or use the [Switch Off violation plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin) to exclude "Duplicated code" violations.

Note that the 2nd option (use of the switch off plugin) works only if you're using the [SQALE plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/sqale/), which embeds the "sqale-java:DuplicatedBlocksCheck" rule.

Comment: I'm a little unsure how to use this Switch Off violation plugin with default sonar rules. What should it look like?
com.projetc.dto.*;"Duplicated code";*
com.projetc.dto.*;duplicated_lines;*
What is the correct name of this rule?

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more precise about the use of the switch off violation plugin.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I am doing everything right, but it simply does not seem to work. When I try with simply putting:
     com.project.dto.*;*;*
nothing changes. Do you have any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Removing the duplications themselves is not possible unless you excludes the corresponding files (with "sonar.exclusions"). Using the switch off violation plugin will juste "mute" the "sqale-java:DuplicatedBlocksCheck" violations (but I guess you're not using the SQALE plugin so you probably don't have such violations). In other words, the only solution is to exclude the files from the analysis.

Comment: The [Switch off violation plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin) is now deprecated. The features have been incorporated into SorarQube itself.

Comment: Hello. I configured "block exclusion" with begin/end patterns but it seems to have no effect on lines duplication analysis (whereas it works well for other violation). Is that behaviour expected ?

Answer (score 65):

With a newer SonarQube installation, you can use `sonar.cpd.exclusions` to exclude certain files only from duplicate checks.
See: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/

Example:

```
sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/AssemblyInfo.cs,**/*.g.cs,**/Mappings/*.cs
```

Comment: How can we do in the pom.xml file ?

Comment: This key isn't part of the documentation, unfortunately. However, the key `sonar.cpd.exclusions` is shown in the SonarQube settings when you navigate to: Project settings > General Settings > Analysis Scope.

Comment: This is the correct answer for modern Sonar versions -- the accepted answer was the only workaround back in 2012. Anyone knows why the parameter is still not visible in the documentation?

Comment: @AdrienW the parameter has been removed from the documentation from version 7.X to 8.X so it's definitely not "still not visible" in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can add these files to the properties in your *pom.xml*:

**This one is to exclude from code coverage:**

```xml
<sonar.coverage.exclusions>
  your file paths
</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
```

**This one is to exclude from code duplication:**

```xml
<sonar.cpd.exclusions>
  your file paths
</sonar.cpd.exclusions>
```

Comment: I believe it's `sonar` instead of `sonarcube` ;)

Comment: <properties>
<sonar.coverage.exclusions>
   **/component/*,
   **/constants/*,
   **/config/*,
   **/dao/*.java,
   **/service/*.java,
   **/abc/Main.java
  </sonar.coverage.exclnusions>
  
  <sonar.cpd.exclusions>
     **/vo/*.java,
     **/entity/*.java
  </sonar.cpd.exclusions>
  
 </properties>

Answer (score 2):

For me works its:

```
<sonar.cpd.exclusions>
  com.simulate.java.dto\**
<\sonar.cpd.exclusions>
```

I have mult modules java projects just like that:

```
- parent
--  project-a
--  project-b
--  project-c
```

in the pom.xml of parent project inside of tag `<properties>` i put:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>

        <sonar.cpd.exclusions>
                com.simulate.java.vo\**,
                com.simulate.java.dto\**
        <\sonar.cpd.exclusions>
<\properties>
```

Just like that. I hope I helped you.

Comment: Hey, @rlresende. Any chance you can provide details?

Comment: Hi @f.khantsis of course. I described better my solution. I hope I helped you.